# CosmosDBClient in Azure CosmosDB v4 Java SDK

Tags: azure, database-connection, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have recently started using Azure cosmos DB v4 Java SDK. One of the [Performance Tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-java-sdk-v4-sql) by Microsoft is:

"Use a singleton [Azure Cosmos DB client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.cosmosasyncclient?view=azure-java-stable) for the lifetime of your application"

I want clarification on a few things mentioned below:

1. Shall I create an Azure Cosmos DB client instance in each Repository/Dao file dedicated to a container or a single instance that can be injected into the Repository/Dao file.
2. What should be the criteria to set value of "maxConnectionsPerEndpoint" in [DirectConnectionConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.directconnectionconfig?view=azure-java-stable) in both the cases?

Comment: A Singleton is often defined per account. If your app accesses 1 account and 50 containers, but all the containers are in the same account, then you should have 1 client. A client can work with any container inside the same account.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta thanks for your response. May I know what's the difference between having one instance per account with a connection pool size of 1000 and 10 instances i.e one for each container belonging to the same account with a connection pool size of 100?

Comment: It's more about latency and connection sharing. The SDK requires initialization, why pay the initialization/latency cost 10 times for no benefit? The same with connection sharing, some containers might have the same backend endpoints (being on the same account), why use more connections? The client is bound to an account, not to a container, so the recommendation is 1 Singleton client per account you interact with.